# How to control user access for Kafka Topics?

Tags: apache-kafka, access-control

Is there a way to Authorize and Restrict access controls on Kafka Topics?

Answer (score 1):

Not yet but it's currently under discussion. 
Have a look at the [Authorization Interface proposal](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/KAFKA/KIP-11+-+Authorization+Interface) and the corresponding [Jira ticket](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/KAFKA-1688)

Comment: Thank you, however is there a notion of creating users in Kafka currently?